# How to create Unicode characters in iTextSharp?

Tags: unicode, itext

I am trying to create the Greek character [phi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi) in iTextSharp along with a number of other characters. I managed to do this by outputing:

```
Convert.ToChar(593)
```

When I look at the [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi) though, phi can be represented by

```
U+03A6 (934 decimal)
U+03C6 (966 decimal)
U+03D5 (965 decimal)
U+0278 (632 decimal)
```

However when I try

```
Convert.ToChar(934)
Convert.ToChar(966)
Convert.ToChar(965)
Convert.ToChar(632)
```

I get blanks.

How do I output these Unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the problem isn't the character value, but the encoding of the font[s] used to display that character.

If a given font/encoding cannot display a given character, you get a blank.  When in doubt, use BaseFont.IDENTITY_H encoding.  If that character (well... "glyph" really) exists in that font, you'll have access to it.  You can even ask a BaseFont if it can display a given character (IIRC taking its glyphs and encoding into account) with `myBaseFont.charExists(int)`.